# Как выполнить функцию только после клика?

Tags: javascript

Сейчас функция выглядит так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function First () {
    var ds = buftitile;
    console.log(buftitile);}
</script>
```

хоть она и обвёрнута в window.onload всё равно функция выполнятся при загрузки страницы.

Comment: Но событие onload это как раз такое специальное событие которое происходит при загрузке страницы

Comment: а как связан клик и загрузка страницы? Это разные события.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо выполнять после каждого клика, то

```
document.onlick = function() {
    var ds = buftitile;
    console.log(buftitile);
}
```